# Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync from `expo-facebook` fails on Android with error `An error occurred while trying to log in to Facebook`

Tags: android, react-native, facebook, expo

I have a redux thunk action for logging in with Facebook in the app I am working on. The action looks like this:

```
export const loginFB = createAsyncThunk('loginFB', async (_, thunkApi) => {
  await Facebook.initializeAsync({ appId: 'aaa', appName: 'bbb' });
  const FBResponse = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync({ permissions: ['public_profile'] });
  if (FBResponse.type === 'success') {
    // Login in backend. Not really relevant 
  }
});
```

This works perfectly on iOS and worked well on Android for a long time (from September 2021 I think). I don't know exactly when it happened, but it recently stopped working on Android. The error message I'm getting looks like this:

```
An error occurred while trying to log in to Facebook
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js:104:50 in promiseMethodWrapper
at node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/NativeModulesProxy.native.js:27:27 in moduleName.methodInfo.name
at node_modules/expo-facebook/build/Facebook.js:69:36 in logInWithReadPermissionsAsync
at node_modules/expo-facebook/build/Facebook.js:64:7 in logInWithReadPermissionsAsync
at src/screens/LoginScreen.tsx:151:41 in FacebookButton.props.onPress
- ... 16 more stack frames from framework internals
```

If the Facebook app is installed on the Android device, a Facebook loading modal briefly appears before disappearing. If it's not installed this message pops up: [Screenshot of Facebook error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xHur.jpg)

I have followed every step in the [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/facebook/) and added hashes of both `Upload key certificate` and `App signing key certificate` from the Play Console used to sign the app. The Facebook developer Android platform is configured like this: [Facebook Developer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXpAR.png).

The code hasn't been touched since it was working except for this addition to the `app.json`:

```
{
  "expo": {
    ...
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-facebook",
        {
          "userTrackingPermission": false
        }
      ]
    ],
    ...
  }
}
```

I have tried removing this addition, but the same error occurs.

Using Expo `44.0.5` and expo-facebook version `12.1.0`

I really don't know how to approach this problem anymore, please help

**UPDATE: 01.02.2022**

The problem has been temporarily solved by downgrading to Expo SDK 43. I still don't know the cause of the problem, but it seems to work well. [The changelog](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) doesn't document any breaking changes with `expo-facebook`.

**UPDATE: 20.09.2022**

The problem has been solved by upgrading to Expo SDK 46 and use [`react-native-fbsdk-next`](https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next) instead of `expo-facebook`. I guess this solution was inevitable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the exact same versions as you're using.

The way that I fixed it atm was to change the behaviour for Android, so when I'm initialising `Facebook.initializeAsync` instead of passing an object I'm just sending the `appId` param.

So it will look something like this:

```
    let options = null;
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      options = '<APP_ID>';
    }
    else {
      options = {
        appId: '<APP_ID>',
        version: 'v9.0',
        appName: '<APP_NAME>',
      };
    }

    await Facebook.initializeAsync(options);
```

Hope this works for you as well.

Comment: This didnt work in my case.